Modify COUNTIF Formula to count inside parenthesis
I have the following formula that I am using to count the number of occurrences of there being a value of 0 out of a number (i.e. 0/2 , 0/5, 0/1, etc...) in a given range of cells.
=COUNTIF(Z7:Z30,"0/*")

This works fine as long as the data in the above range (Z7:Z30) is formatted as the above i.e. 0/3, 1/2, etc.. however there the way users will be putting data into this cell range going forward will have a set of parenthesis around them - i.e. (2.00/3.00) but when the parenthesis is used the Formula is not counting the 0's records. So I believe I either need to have a formula in the cell data range that automatically removes the set of parenthesis as the users paste the data (with parenthesis) into Excel, or I need to adjust the formula above that is counting the 0/ records to essentially ignore the parenthesis.
I could not find an easy solution with the first option as I don't want to require my users to enter the data somewhere else for it to then reflect without the parenthesis in the cell range, so I was looking more at the 2nd option of modifying the above formula, however when I try to combine the above formula with a SUBSTITUTE formula to remove the parenthesis I am getting an error. This is what I tried to accomplish this:
=COUNTIF(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Z7:Z30, "(", ""), ")", ""),"0/*")

This formula works appropriately IF the data is formatted without the parenthesis, however once the parenthesis is put around the data then it does not work:

Below I am using the SUBSTITUTE formula to remove the parenthesis from cell Z29 above it. I either want to be able to utilize this formula in the actual cell range that the users are inputting the data into and have it re-format to remove the parenthesis, OR I need to be able to combine the below formula into the COUNTIF formula above (prefer whatever the simplest solution is).

Hope I have explained this well enough but please let me know if I can clarify anything, thanks in advance!

…  What's wrong with =COUNTIF(Z7:Z30,"0/*")+COUNTIF(Z7:Z30,"(0/*")?

Suggestion by Chronocidal could be sufficient for your needs. But if you want to handle space in front of zeros or zero with decimals :) etc., you could try:
=LET(
    cols, C4:L5,
    zeros_in_col, LAMBDA(c,
        SUM(--(--TOCOL(TEXTBEFORE(SUBSTITUTE(c, "(", ""), "/"), 2) = 0))
    ),
    IFERROR(BYCOL(cols, zeros_in_col), "")
)


